# How to switch Resque environment from development to test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, resque

I'm very new to rails and recently I'm trying to use [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) and Rspec to test my codes.
What I'm stocked with is to change Resque environment to test.

This is my state:

1. Redis-server is lunched: port 6379, PID: 6046
2. resque-web is lunched:

> ```
> $ resque-web
> [2014-09-19 21:52:43 +0430] Starting 'resque-web'...
> [2014-09-19 21:52:43 +0430] trying port 5678...
> Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console</li>
> ```
>
> Now I can see resque web console at `http://0.0.0.0:5678/stats/resque`

Well, on `Stats` tab, there's a table and at the first row, environment is set to development.

- Resque Client connected to redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0
- environment  development
- failed   0
- pending  0
- processed    37780
- queues   0
- servers  ["redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0"]
- workers  0
- working  0

I want to set Resque environment to test, so that I test jobs created by my rspec tests using test database, but I don't know how.Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set the `RAILS_ENV` environment variable before running `resque-web`, e.g.

```
$ RAILS_ENV=test resque-web
```